# python2.7 xlsxwriter doesn't write more then 65533 rows

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlsxwriter

Hi I am tring to create a xlsx file but, I can write more the 65533 rows
the object I am using is Xlsxwriter?

how can I write more rows?

Comment: The current xlsxwriter release respects Excel 2007 limitations which is 1048576 maw rows. Note that older _excel_ versions are limited to 65536 rows so your problem might come from the Excel version you use, not xlsxwriter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple test:

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("test.xlsx")
sheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
for i in range(1, 70000):
    sheet.write('B' + str(i), "Blub")
workbook.close()
```

After that I have opened the file test.xlsx in Libreoffice, eh voila :)

[image: Libreoffice]